# I'm not sure why but it just says "Done!" 3 seconds before it should say "Purchasing..."

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function Purchase() {
    document.getElementById("Button1").innerHTML = "Purchasing..."
    window.setTimeout(Purchase(), 30000)
    document.getElementById("Button1").innerHTML = "Done!"
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a fun little purchasing code test (I know it won't actually buy anything though).

Comment: remove the () from Purchase()

Comment: Also done is executed immediately after you call setTimeout, so move done to the end of function Purchase

Comment: What is it that you *think* your code is doing? What do you think that `setTimeout` line is going to do?

Answer (score 3):

```
function Purchase() {
    document.getElementById("Button1").innerHTML = "Purchasing..."
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("Button1").innerHTML = "Done!"
    }, 3000)  
}
```

is that what you need?

A couple of issues in your post:
`30000` in milliseconds is 30 seconds

Also, you were calling `Purchase()` inside of your `Purchase` function making your function recursive and will make Purchase being executed over and over again

Also, `setTimeout` takes a function reference (not a function execution) as the first argument that will be executed after the interval you set as the second argument. Adding `()` in `setTimeout(Purchase())` will cause the `Purchase` function to be executed straight away.

Comment: Oh, thanks, this works nicely!